# Polymer Change values in templates on google map marker

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, google-maps-markers, polymer-2.x

I have a template in an other template. The values does not change in the inner template when I set them?

Here is where I set my address:

```
selectAddress: function (e) {
  this.set('location.city', e.model.item.city);
  this.set('location.countryCode', e.model.item.country);
};
```

Here is my property object:

```
location: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true,
      value: function () {
        return {
          city: "",
          countryCode: ""
        }
      }
```

And here is the HTML and templates I want the values to change in:

```
<div page-name="main-page">
      <span id="locationCity">{{location.city}}</span> <!-- Here the  value is changing correctly. -->

    <google-map id="map" map="{{map}}" latitude="{{googleData.lat}}" longitude="{{googleData.long}}" zoom="{{googleData.zoom}}"
      api-key="XXX">

      <template id="google-marker-template" is="dom-if" if="{{showMarker}}">
        <google-map-marker draggable="false" latitude="{{markerLat}}" longitude="{{markerLong}}" click-events="true" on-google-map-marker-click="markerClicked"
          open="true">
          <template is="dom-if" if="{{!pickAddress}}">
            <div>
              <span id="locationCountryCode">{{location.countryCode}}</span> <!-- Here the value is never changing?! -->
              <span id="locationCity">{{location.city}}</span> <!-- Here the value is never changing?! -->
            </div>
          </template>
          <template is="dom-if" if="{{pickAddress}}">
            <div>
              <span>Choose address</span>
            </div>
          </template>
        </google-map-marker>
      </template>
    </google-map>
```

As you can see I have a `dom-if`. Thats the reason I need to have template in an other template. So when the values is changing, the text is still the "old value" and is never changing on `{{location.countryCode` and `{{location.city}}`.
The first time I set the values it works fine (whene `location` is empty) , but if I go and try to change them again it always stays with the old values.

Anyone who knows why the values still are the same.

**EDIT:**
I change my code a bit. Still dosent work tho.

```
 <google-map id="map" map="{{map}}" latitude="{{googleData.lat}}" longitude="{{googleData.long}}" zoom="{{googleData.zoom}}"
      api-key="XXX">

      <dom-if if="{{showMarker}}">
        <template>
          <google-map-marker draggable="false" latitude="{{markerLat}}" longitude="{{markerLong}}" click-events="true" on-google-map-marker-click="markerClicked"
            open="true">

            <dom-if if="{{location.hasValue}}">
              <template>
                <div>
                  <span id="locationCity">{{location.city}}</span>
                </div>
              </template>
            </dom-if>

            <dom-if if="{{!location.hasValue}}">
              <template>
                <div>
                  <span>Choose address</span>
                </div>
              </template>
            </dom-if>


          </google-map-marker>
        </template>
      </dom-if>

    </google-map>
```

And added `hasValue` to my location property.

Comment: How you are getting 'pickAddress' value? It should be the property in Polymer.

Comment: The 'pickAddress' is just a property im setting in different functions. To show or hide the different templates

Comment: You still have to add that property to your element's `properties` map, in order for DOM bindings to work.

Comment: Okey. I updated my code a little bit. Im obviously missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#type-extension), you have to wrap the outermost `template is="dom-if"` (or `is="dom-repeat"`, for that matter) in the respective helper element when upgrading to Polymer 2, i.e. `<dom-if/>` or `<dom-repeat/>`.

EDIT:

Also, there you should consider some additional details from *google-map-marker*'s API:

> **Breaking changes:**
>   Markers added to google-map must now specify slot="markers" to be
>   added correctly.

and:

> The `google-map-marker` element represents a map marker. It is used as a
>   child of `google-map`.

While the former should be an easy fix, solving the latter problem depends on whether it has to be a **direct** child or not. (API spec doesn't elaborate on that.)
There's an open GitHub issue, with [one comment](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/168#issuecomment-122397147) saying it should be a direct child. (The comment predates definition of the *slot* API, though.)

I suppose you should first check if removing the `<dom-if>` between `<google-map>` and `<google-map-marker>` helps. If so, I'd open a GitHub  issue and try to find a workaround meanwhile.

Comment: Okey. I made some changes to the code. I put a `hasValue` on my location property and then made the 
`<dom-if if="{{location.hasValue}}">
   <template> ... {{location.city}} ... </template>
</dom-if>`. 

But it just works the same.

Comment: I'm still running Polymer 1.9.x and my `dom-if`s look like `<dom-if><template is="dom-if" if="[[...]]">...</template></dom-if>`

Comment: Okey. My problem is that the values is not changing. The `dom-if` is working fine. Its just the `location.city` and `location.countryCode` that "holds" the values even tho the property is changing.The `location.city` is changing outside the template correctly, but not inside the template

Comment: @JohanByrén: I added some more hints.

Comment: I have the `<dom-if>` on the marker of the reason I get an error second time I open my window, the marker is trying to set before the google map is ready. But I tried now to remove it just for this test-case but unfortunately it didn't change anything. But the problem seems to be with the google marker info window, that it cant handle the change?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't add **reflectToAttribute** property for location. The **reflectToAttribute** property tells Polymer to update the corresponding attribute when the property changes.

So change location property as follows

```
location: {
  type: Object,
  notify: true,
  reflectToAttribute: true,
  value: function () {
    return {
      city: "",
      countryCode: ""
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this earlier and I´m very sad that this not seems to do any different

Comment: can you try with <template is="dom-if" if={{condition}}> format.